# How can i fix my bouncing ball glitching through the bottom of my screen?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

If your run it once the ball is about to stop it starts skipping up and down a little bit and disappears through the floor.

So i was following the kivy tutorial for the pong game and half way through i thought why not make the ball have gravity...i kind of figured that out though I don't know wether it's good code or not but that's not my problem. I already compared it to some other code basically doing the same and didn't find any differences. Could somebody tell me what i have done wrong? (Sorry i had to paste all my code in here but i don't know where the problem is...)

```
import kivy
kivy.require("1.10.1")

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
from random import randint


class PongBall(Widget):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)

    def update_speed(self):
        self.velocity[1] = self.velocity[1] - 15/60

        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos


class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)

    def serve_ball(self):
        self.ball.center = self.center
        self.ball.velocity = Vector(0, 0)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.ball.update_speed()

        if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
            self.ball.velocity_y *= -1

        if (self.ball.x < 0) or (self.ball.right > self.width):
            self.serve_ball()


class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        game.serve_ball()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0/60.0)
        return game


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

This is my kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1


<PongBall>:
    size: 50, 50
    canvas:
        Ellipse:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size


<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball

    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.center_x - 5, 0
            size: 10, self.height

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width / 4
        top: root.height * 9 / 10
        text: "0"

    Label:
        font_size: 70
        center_x: root.width * 3 / 4
        top: root.height * 9 / 10
        text: str(pong_ball.velocity[1])

    PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        center: self.parent.center
```

I want the ball to slow down until it lays on the ground and doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is just a common problem with floats ...

just in your update speed function do something like

```
if velocity <= 1e-6: # some really small number
   velocity = 0.0
```

its also probably a good idea to fix your y position in your move function

```
if (self.ball.y < 0) or (self.ball.top > self.height):
   self.ball.y = 0.1
   self.ball.velocity_y *= -1
```

Comment: Ok thank you. I'll try it out first thing tomorrow.

Comment: ```
def update_speed(self):
        self.velocity[1] = self.velocity[1] - 15/60

        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos

        if self.velocity[1] <= 1e-6: # some really small number
            self.velocity[1] = 0.0
```
So i put this into my update_speed function and now it just moves at an extremely slow pace. I think the speed in the beginning is just not high enough so it always resets to 0. Is there any fix for this?

Comment: you can make the threshold smaller `1e-10`? or you can make your initial velocity more  :/